# Difference between Metaspace and Native Memory in Java

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, nio, metaspace

What is the difference between **Metaspace** and **Native memory**?

Metaspace can be tracked using jconsole, jvisualvm, jstat cmds.
It seems Native Memory can be tracked using jcmd. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html)

Is metaspace also Native Memory?

Where do NIO buffers get stored? In the metaspace or native memory?

Answer (score 28):

**Is metaspace also Native Memory?**

> Yes, Metaspace is part of the Native Memory(process memory) and is
>   limited by host operating system

[image: source http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-8/]
You can monitor it using `jmap -permstat PID`. If your application ends up allocating lot of memory in metaspace then it will effect the **entire system** not just the JVM.That's why its recommended that you use `-XX:MetaspaceSize` to explicitly set the max metaspace size for your app.

> Java NIO APIs use ByteBuffers as the source and destination of I/O
>   calls, and come in two flavours:
>
> - Heap Byte Buffer (wrap a byte[] array, allocated in the garbage collected Java heap)
> - Direct Byte Buffer (wrap memory allocated outside the Java heap )
>
> Since only "native" memory can be passed to operating system calls, so
>   it won't be moved by the garbage collector, it means that when you use
>   a **heap ByteBuffer** for I/O, it is copied into a **temporary direct
>   ByteBuffer**. The JDK caches one temporary buffer per thread, without
>   any memory limits (i.e. an unbounded cache). As a result, **if you
>   call I/O methods with large heap ByteBuffers from multiple threads,
>   your process can use a huge amount of additional native memory**.

You can refer to [this](http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-8/) & [this article](http://www.evanjones.ca/java-bytebuffer-leak.html) for more details.

**Updated**

**RSS**=OffHeap (mapped files, JVM internal code (.bss segments), thread stacks, direct buffers) + GC internal structure+ Heap + Structures used & allocated by native libraries (e.g IO libraries) + Metaspace + Shared Libraries of the JVM + CodeCache

You can use, on linux [pmap -x](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) to analyse the memory map of your JVM process. Furthermore, [Jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc) can help to write a profile to disk after every x GB/ x kB of memory allocation/stack trace by setting appropriate [MALLOC_CONF env variables](http://www.canonware.com/download/jemalloc/jemalloc-latest/doc/jemalloc.html#tuning). Once you have a generated file try using 
Jeprof for [visualisation](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case%3A-Leak-Checking). E.g.

```
 jeprof --show_bytes --pdf `which w` jeprof.heap > sample.pdf
```

to generate the PDF for call graphs.

Comment: I am using Tomcat enabled with NIO connectors. RSS value in `ps` unix cmd is not matching with (heap+metaspace). So if native memory is more than metaspace, how to measure it. And if possible could you mention the break up  of memory used(RSS)

Comment: There can be lot of reasons like to many threads, may be problem with glibc version > 2.10, etc. You can use `pmap - x` to get more insight into the memory.

Comment: A large chunk of your answer has been copied from http://www.evanjones.ca/java-bytebuffer-leak.html

Comment: @TheLostMind I reformatted my post , for some reason the formatting was not applied properly the first time. It should be fine now

Comment: if metaspace is part of native memory and its usage can be tracked, then how to track the overall native memory usage? I am able to track heap, metaspace. But still need to account for memory difference of RSS(resident memory) - Heap -Metaspace . This difference for me varies from 200MB till around 1GB.

Comment: JVM also need some memory for internals .`RSS=OffHeap (mapped files, JVM internal code (.bss segments), thread stacks, direct buffers) + GC internal structure+ Heap + Structures used & allocated by native libraries (e.g IO libraries) + Meatspace + Shared Libraries of the JVM + CodeCache` . Did you tried `pmap -x` & analysed the output? Are you experiencing some memory errors? You can also use `Jemalloc` to write a profile to disk after every x GB/ x kB of memory allocation/stack trace by setting MALLOC_CONF env variables & use jeprof to visualise the generated file

Comment: HotSpot (JVM implementation) also has something called Native Memory Tracking which can be used to see exactly how much memory are used for the different internal data structures. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html

Comment: I knew about metaspace, but until this answer, I'd never heard about "meatspace" Is that where the JVM allocates memory for tube steak?